# Segmentation fault error C++

Tags: c++, memory, vector

Im writing a simple program that alternates two vectors and push_backs's them into a 3rd vector however i get a segmentation fault error (core dumped). I did some research and it seems to be I'm accessing memory that either isn't there or I'm not supposed to. I know this a simple fix but I'm pretty new to C++ so anything would be appreciated.

```
vector<int> alternate(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    int n = a.size();
    int m = b.size();

    vector<int> c(n + m);

    int i;

    for(i = 0; i < a.size() and i < b.size (); i++)
    {
        c.push_back(a[i]);
        c.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    return c;
}

int main () {

    vector<int> a,b,c;
    int temp1;
    int temp2;

    while (temp1 != -1) {
        cin >> temp1;
        if(temp1 == -1) {
            break;
        }
        a.push_back(temp1);
    }

    while (temp2 != -1) {
        cin >> temp2;
        if(temp2 == -1) {
            break;
        }
        b.push_back(temp2);
    }

    c = alternate(a,b);

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < c.size(); i++) {
        cout << c[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Straight off the bat you have undefined behaviour by using a variable without a value. You should look to fixing that first, since by its very nature undefined behaviour can cause anything to happen

Comment: If you have access to one, you should step through your code with a debugger. Even without one, you can use a bunch of `std::cout` statements to show you where the code is going and what values everything is.

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to step through your program and see where the crash happened?

Comment: Thank you for your help :) I'll tinker with the variables and see what works

Comment: Fei Xiang No I haven't. I've never used a debugger before, I'm pretty new lol. I'll check that out thank you :)

Comment: Change `while (<variable> != 1)` to `while (true)`. You're already checking for `-1` inside the loop, it's not necessary to check again.

Comment: @Barmar Or better: `while (std:cin >> temp && temp != -1)`.

Comment: @O'Neil For a beginner, it's better to keep it simple, rather than trying to do multiple things in one statement.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you have a two problems here:

1. You used `temp1` and `temp2` in you conditions and you didn't initialize them, that's a UB. Try `int temp1 = 0; int temp2 = 0;`.
2. In function `alternate` you are initializing your returning vector with the sum of your two input vectors like this `vector<int> c(n + m);`, then you use `push_back` to add elements of these inputs. this way you will have `n+m` zeros at start of your returning vector then elements of your input. I'm pretty sure you don't want this. you don't need to give default size to you vector, just use `push_back` or if you insist on using default size then assign values to indexes of your vector.

Comment: For #1 he should just get rid of the code that uses `temp1` and `temp2` before they're set. That code isn't needed.

Comment: @Barmar That's correct, it's kind of useless double check, but anyway it's good practice to always initialize your variables.

Comment: @Hamed Thank you for you help! you were able to point me in the right diection and I was able to solve it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems with your code, some of which are mentioned above. The most important problems are the following:

1. temp1 and temp2 are uninitialized. Depending on your compiler, when accessed in the while loop they may be either 0 or some random number.
2. The final vector will be too big. When you create c you are creating it with a size of n+m hence it already has that many elements, each with a value of 0. Then you are adding the elements of the other vectors resulting in a final vector that is roughly (n+m)*2 in size.
3. I said "roughly" above because another problem is that unless n==m your final vector will be missing the last elements from the larger of a and b. You need to iterate to the larger of n and m, checking in the while loop to ensure you can access items safely.

Other lesser problems are the following:

1. You are making a copy of a and b when you pass them into alternate. By using a const reference you can avoid the copy.
2. Although unlikely, it is possible for a or b to hold more items than can be referenced by an "int". Use a size_t to be safe. Or even better use "auto" to allow the compiler to determine the correct type automatically.
3. Limit the visibility of your temporary variables by bringing them into the "for" and "while" loops.
4. Use the newer vector for loops to avoid the need for indices when possible (it isn't possible in alternate, but it is possible when writing out the final results.

After all that, the result should look something like the following:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<int> alternate(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b)
{
    const auto n = a.size();
    const auto m = b.size();
    const auto N = max(n, m);

    vector<int> c;
    c.reserve(n+m);

    for(size_t i = 0; i < N; ++i)
    {
        if (i < n) c.push_back(a[i]);
        if (i < m) c.push_back(b[i]);
    }

    return c;
}

int main () {

    vector<int> a,b,c;

    while (true) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if(temp == -1) {
            break;
        }
        a.push_back(temp);
    }

    while (true) {
        int temp;
        cin >> temp;
        if(temp == -1) {
            break;
        }
        b.push_back(temp);
    }

    c = alternate(a,b);

    for (auto val : c) {
        cout << val << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thnak you very much @Stephen! I'm a total beginner in C++ (I'm sure you can tell), this was part of a problem for my university courses homework assignment.Thanks for making such a detailed response, it'll definitely help me in the future :)

Comment: @Stephen could you elaborate on how im making a copy of a and b?

Comment: When you have a method signature of "vector<int> a" it makes a copy of "a" and passes it into the function. You can avoid the copy by instead passing in "const vector<int>& a" which passes in a constant reference to the object instead of a copy of the object. A constant reference is essentially a pointer internally so it's cheap, but the compiler will give you errors if you try to change the object. A non-const reference "vector<int>& a" would allow the function to actually make changes to the original object.

Answer (score 0):

As both answers pointed out, uninitialized variables as well as making my 'c' vector too big were the culprits